# Azure AD (IDP) integration with Gigya (SP)

Tags: gigya

I am trying to configure Azure AD (IDP) integration with Gigya (SP) for individual Gigya sites.
I have configured an Azure AD enterprise application and the following configuration is required:

- Identifier (Entity ID)
- Reply URL
- Sign on URL

Could anyone confirm whether the Sign on URL is a Gigya URL and if so what this might look like?

Comment: When attempting to integrate at site level, the Sign on URL is not used and needs to be passed as part of the query string. This is not in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Sign on URL is just http://companyname.gigya.com since it's just your company site on Gigya. You can get the actual values by contacting the [Gigya client support team](https://www.sap.com/support.html).

You can also check this by going to Azure portal > Gigya application integration page > single sign-on > Select a Single sign-on method > SAML/WS-Fed > Set up Single Sign-On with SAML > Edit > **Basic SAML configuration**.

Check out the documentation:

https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-saas-gigya-tutorial.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/gigya-tutorial

Comment: As mentioned I have been trying to do this at site level and not account level. Gigya unfortunately don't know the answer themselves and have had to go away to work it out. The only thing we've worked out is that it is the socialize login url which is available when attempting to test SAML integration is correct, but they're unsure of the additional parameters that are required. It's undocumented on their site.